# Why we only use L1 and L2 in penalized regression

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression, regularization, tikhonov-regularization

I understand we do not want to go lower than 1 because the problem is no longer convex. But why not use L3 for example? Is there any reason why L2 is so popular but not higher norm?